# How to filter dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of dictionaries.

**Sample:**

```
keyList = ['0','1','2']
valueList = [{'Name': 'Nick', 'Age': 39, 'Country': 'UK'}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Age': 19, 'Country': 'Spain'}, {'Name': 'Dave', 'Age': 23, 'Country': 'UK'}]
d = {}
for i in range(len(keyList)):
    d[keyList[i]] = valueList[i]
```

**Output:**

```
{'0': {'Name': 'Nick', 'Age': 39, 'Country': 'UK'}, '1': {'Name': 'Steve', 'Age': 19, 'Country': 'Spain'}, '2': {'Name': 'Dave', 'Age': 23, 'Country': 'UK'}}
```

**I want to do two things:**

1. filter by **one** string or int value in a value e.g. `Name`, ignoring case. I.e. remove any `key/value` where a string/int is found. So if 'Nick' is found in `Name`, remove the `key` '0' and its value completely:

`{'1': {'Name': 'Steve', 'Age': 19, 'Country': 'Spain'}, '2': {'Name': 'Dave', 'Age': 23, 'Country': 'UK'}}`

2. The same as above, but with a list of strings instead. I.e. filter and remove any `keys` where any of the following strings `["uK", "Italy", "New Zealand"]` appear in Country, ignoring case.

`{'1': {'Name': 'Steve', 'Age': 19, 'Country': 'Spain'}}`

I was hoping the below would work for one string, but I think it only works if it is just one dictionary rather than a dictionary of dictionaries, so its not working for me:

```
filtered_d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if "nick".casefold() not in v["Name"]}
```

Any suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: It seems to be the issue with case. This should work
`filtered_d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if "nick".casefold() not in v["Name"].casefold()}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is one level of nesting in the dictionary (not a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries), you could use the following function which iterates over the keys and filters as per the supplied values:

```py
from typing import List

def remove_from_dict(key_name: str, values: List[str], dictionary: dict):
    values = [value.casefold() for value in values]

    filtered_dict = {
        key: inner_dict
        for key, inner_dict in dictionary.items()
        if inner_dict[key_name].casefold() not in values
    }

    return filtered_dict


dictionary = {
    "0": {"Name": "Nick", "Age": 39, "Country": "UK"},
    "1": {"Name": "Steve", "Age": 19, "Country": "Spain"},
    "2": {"Name": "Dave", "Age": 23, "Country": "UK"},
}

# Output: {'1': {'Name': 'Steve', 'Age': 19, 'Country': 'Spain'}, '2': {'Name': 'Dave', 'Age': 23, 'Country': 'UK'}}
print(remove_from_dict("Name", ["Nick"], dictionary))
# Output: {'1': {'Name': 'Steve', 'Age': 19, 'Country': 'Spain'}}
print(remove_from_dict("Country", ["uK", "Italy", "New Zealand"], dictionary))
```

Update:

If we want to account for partial matches, we have to use `re` module.

```py
import re
from typing import List, Optional


dictionary = {
    "0": {"Name": "Nick", "Age": 39, "Country": "UK"},
    "1": {"Name": "Steve", "Age": 19, "Country": "Spain"},
    "2": {"Name": "Dave", "Age": 23, "Country": "UK"},
}


def remove_from_dict(
    key_name: str,
    values: List[str],
    dictionary: dict,
    use_regex: Optional[bool] = False,
):
    values = [value.casefold() for value in values]

    regular_comparator = lambda string: string.casefold() not in values
    # if the string matches partially with anything in the list, 
    # we need to discard that dictionary. 
    regex_comparator = lambda string: not any(
        re.match(value, string.casefold()) for value in values
    )

    comparator = regex_comparator if use_regex else regular_comparator

    filtered_dict = {
        key: inner_dict
        for key, inner_dict in dictionary.items()
        if comparator(inner_dict[key_name])
    }

    return filtered_dict


# Output: {}, all dictionaries removed
print(remove_from_dict("Country", ["uK", "Spa"], dictionary, use_regex=True))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just checking this on my real dataset :)

Comment: There isn't a way of checking for part values easily is there i.e. if I was to search for "Zealand" instead of "New Zealand", it would still find it?

Comment: You would have to use regex in that case. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Wow, thank you SO much. This is amazing. This has helped me so much!